# No such file or directory error (nginx)

Tags: nginx

I just updated the favicons of my website and my nginx logs are flooded with errors of the sort `open() "/home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj/img/favicons/site.webmanifest" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 131.191.99.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /static/img/favicons/site.webmanifest?v=2 HTTP/1.1"`.

According to this error, the GET request is to `/static/img/favicons/site.webmanifest?v=2` which is causing nginx to try open `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj/img/favicons/site.webmanifest`. Nginx is skipping the `static` directory for some odd reason.

In other words, this error is indeed correct - the actual location is `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj/static/img/favicons/site.webmanifest` (note the `static` folder).

How do I change nginx configuration to fix this issue? Note that I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy alongwith a gunicorn application server (it's a Django app).

---

Comment: Please show your `nginx` configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked the following server block:

```
location /static {

    access_log off;
    alias /home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj;
}
```

And changed it to:

```
location /static {

    access_log off;
    root /home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj;
}
```

This now correctly maps the location of my `/static/` folder and the error is gone.

For the uninitiated, note that `root` directive ensures the location is `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj/static` whereas using `alias` produces `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myproj`